# Resize desktop smaller than screen resolution

Tags: resolution, desktop

I want to resize my desktop to be smaller than my resolution, meaning that the desktop will be placed at the center of the screen with black bars around it, is it possible?

The reason for that, I'm visually impaired and I want to use Windows 7 magnifier which multiplies the screen so I can only see 1/2 of the desktop when using dual screen, if my question is possible then I could see the whole desktop in zoom mode.

I'm using Windows 7, ATI Radeon 4670.

Comment: Have you considered increasing DPI so text appears larger? Depending on your needs, this might already be sufficient.

Comment: DPI is not enough for me, I need at least x2 magnification, .Thanks, though. And i want to build small app that quickly resize, rotate, magnify the screen etc...

Comment: No idea how to do this, but if you can stand the blurriness, how about reducing resolution? Get a big-ass 27" or 30" screen and use it with 1280x1024? You'll be able to see everything at once. Another option would be to look into TV TFT screens at that size with fewer native DPI.

Comment: There are 26" TV TFT screens with 1366x768 resolution. This is about 60 DPI. Combined with higher DPI setting in Windows this could be worth a try.